# The following code does not work

Tags: c++, stl

I am using MSVC 2012 and when I compile the program below it says:

> > The term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

I am sure that the problem is with the `mem_fun` and `mem_fun_ref` function call. Please provide a correct way to call the functions.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>

using namespace std;

#define PRINT(A, Sp) copy(A.begin(), A.end(), ostream_iterator<decltype(*A.begin())>(cout, Sp))

struct Generate {
    int a;
    Generate(int a) : a(a) {
    }
    Generate gen() {
        return Generate(rand()%100);
    }
    void testing() {
        vector<Generate> a(5), b, c;
        generate(a.begin(), a.end(), mem_fun(&Generate::gen));
        generate_n(back_inserter(b), 5, mem_fun_ref(&Generate::gen));
    }
};

void main() {
    Generate a(32);
    a.testing();
}
```

Comment: It would help if you indicated which line is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something of the form

```
auto f = mem_fun(&Generate::gen);
```

generates a function that takes an argument of type `Generate`:

```
auto f = mem_fun(&Generate::gen);
Generate g;
auto x = f(g);
```

whereas `std::generate_n` requires a functor taking no arguments.

It looks like you need something of the form

```
std::bind(&Generate::gen, this)
```

Comment: will you please explain a bit clearly why 'std::bind(&Generate::gen, this)' works

Comment: If he has `std::bind`, then he has lambda functions, which are a lot simpler and clearer.

Comment: @TamojitChatterjee `Generate::gen` is a non-static member function, so it takes an implicit first parameter for `this`. `std::bind` in this case creates a function object which will call`Generate::gen` with the bound parameter (`this` in my example). This means you can call it without arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that functor returned by `mem_fun` will have a `operator()` that takes 1 argument of type `Generate*` but the functor used by `std::generate` should take no parameters.

If `gen` doesn't need access to class data, you can make it `static` and get rid of `mem_fun` altogether:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
#define PRINT(A, Sp) copy(A.begin(), A.end(), ostream_iterator<decltype(*A.begin())>(cout, Sp))
struct Generate {
    int a;
    Generate() {}
    Generate(int a) : a(a) {
    }
    static Generate gen() {
        return Generate(rand()%100);
    }
    void testing() {
        vector<Generate> a(5), b, c;
        generate(a.begin(), a.end(), &Generate::gen);
        generate_n(back_inserter(b), 5, &Generate::gen);
    }
};

int main() {
    Generate a(32);
    a.testing();
}
```

This compiles fine after I added default constructor and made `main` return int.

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct Generate {
    int a;
    Generate(int a) : a(a) {
    }
    Generate(){}
    Generate gen() {
        return Generate(rand()%100);
    }
    void testing() {
        vector<Generate> a(5), b, c;
        generate(a.begin(), a.end(), bind(mem_fun(&Generate::gen), this));
        generate_n(back_inserter(b), 5, bind(mem_fun(&Generate::gen), this));
    }
};
```

I chang the code to this.

Comment: what exactly is the 'this' doing.